# What are some deviations from GBA emulators such as GameTime Player?

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

I recently took a liking to GBA's and playing pokemon and turn based tactic games, but I cannot find any suitable online emulators that allow me to load a file in and play. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Boy Advance v 1.8.0 should be sufficient for any working GBA rom or romhack.

Here's a description of its features: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualBoyAdvance#Features

If you run into failures (blank screen), make sure that Options → Emulators → Save Type is set to Flash 128k

Here's a guide for additional settings options and configuration (I'm unaffiliated with the channel, but the video is helpful):